# How to resize large tooltip in D3Plus

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I am using tree maps in d3plus and set its large tooltip property with .html key like below.

```
            .tooltip({
            "share":false,
            "html" : "Summary information about the Service, and may be some links to the external applications"
        })
```

However in my case it seems much bigger than necessary, as shown below. 
Is there a ways to resize it ?

[image: d3plus large tooltip]

Comment: Use CSS properties width, height to auto. If you can't do this, make a fiddle then we could do something on it.

Comment: here my jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/kasimsert/wLvpph35/3/  can I do it with d3 selectors instead of css? i tried but didn't work.

Comment: the jsfiddle is not working, can you correct that?